# Java program to run linux command to check if server is running

Tags: java, linux

I am running Java code to check if Jetty server is running in Linux or not. The way I am trying to do it is as below

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ps", "-ef" });

InputStream input = p1.getInputStream();

Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "grep", "/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/jetty/start.jar"});

OutputStream output = p2.getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(input, output);

output.close(); // signals grep to finish

List<String> result = IOUtils.readLines(p2.getInputStream());

System.out.println(result);
```

The problem with above code is that it gives me two outputs like this:

```
xxxxx    1111 44444  0 11:22 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/jetty/start.jar

xxxxx   22222     1  2 Oct21 ?        04:03:55 xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/jetty/start.jar`
```

1. The jetty server process which was running previously but killed sometime
2. The jetty server process which is currently running

How do I get just the one record of the current running process? I do know commands in linux which fetch me only the running process as the output but fail when integrated in my Java code.

Looking for a solution that would give the running process and also works with Java or Java code in which I could run something like ps -ef | grep /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/jetty/start.jar | grep -v grep

Or

ps -fC java | grep /xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/jetty/start.jar runs in linux but not in Java

Comment: Actually that looks like normal, unfiltered grep output - one command saying, "Oh hey, you ran grep with this command", and the other actually finding the command you want.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74185/13623

Comment: How do we use it in Java? Any code would help!